# Getting a weird java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for my classes

Tags: java, methods, runtime-error, nodes, treenode

I am trying to implement TreeNodes and BSTs and I have written two files to start me off. However, even at this point I am getting a really weird error. At runtime I am being told a method that clearly exists doesn't exist.

Here are both of the classes for your reference.

**BST.java**

```
public class BST {

    TreeNode root;

    public BST(int data) {
        this.root = new TreeNode(data);
    }

    public boolean insert(int data) {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(data);
        TreeNode curr = root;
        boolean inTree = false;

        while (!inTree) {

            // newNode is <= curr, place in left
            if (newNode.getValue() <= curr.getValue()) {

                if (curr.getLeft() != null) {
                    curr = curr.getLeft();
                } else {
                    curr.setLeft(newNode);
                    inTree = true;
                    System.out.println(data+" INSERTED LEFT OF "+curr);
                }

            } else {

                if (curr.getRight() != null) {
                    curr = curr.getRight();
                } else {
                    curr.setRight(newNode);
                    System.out.println(data+" INSERTED Right OF "+curr);
                    inTree = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BST bsTree = new BST(4);

        bsTree.insert(1);
        bsTree.insert(4);
        bsTree.insert(0);
    }
}
```

Running `javac Main.java` is fine but when I run `java Main` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: BST.<init>(I)V
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? Thanks

**[EDIT]:** Even MORE weird stuff happening.

Let's say I make a completely new folder in a different directory and put this file:

```
public class BST {

    TreeNode root;

    public BST(int val) {
        TreeNode r = new TreeNode(val);
        root = r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hey");
     }
}
```

Compiling it works but running it just gives me no results and doesn't terminate. However, if I rename the class to `BSTe` and change the file name accordingly it works...what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the compiled class `BST` in your classpath.

Try:

```
 Java -cp ./ Main
```

Comment: @zach Have you compiled BST? in wich directory BST.class is located?

Comment: Everything is compiled. If I have another BST.java and BST.class in a different directory it shouldn't mess with it...should it?

Comment: @Zach So you have to add the directory wich contains the file BST.class to your classpath `Java -cp <Path to BST.class> Main`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `javac *.java`. This will compile all your class in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work fine. Make sure that you have cleaned your project in your IDE. More specifically make sure that the class `BST` is compiled and updated so that the latest changes areseen by the `Main` class.

You can compile all classes at once using `javac *.java`

Comment: I currently have the classes in a folder and I'm using Sublime Text. I've successfully run `javac *.java` but to no avail...